# How java handles StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Here's my sample app

```
public class Main {

    private long[] exceptionLevels = new long[1000];
    private int index;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        try {
            main.foo(0);
        } finally {
            Arrays.stream(main.exceptionLevels)
                    .filter(x -> x != 0)
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    private void foo(int level) {
        try {
            foo(level + 1);
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            exceptionLevels[index++] = level;
            bar(level + 1);
        }
    }

    private void bar(int level) {
        try {
            bar(level + 1);
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            exceptionLevels[index++] = -level;
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes, when I run the app, I see a result like this

```
8074
8073
-8074
```

Which actually means that the following occured

- foo(8073) calls foo(8074)
- foo(8074) calls foo(8075) which dies
- foo(8074) logs itself and calls bar(8075) which dies
- foo(8074) dies and foo(8073) catches it, logs itself and calls bar(8074)
- bar(8074) calls bar(8075) which dies, so bar(8074) logs itself
- returning from all methods, gracefully shuts down

I get it, everything's fine. So there's an understandable pattern of getting

```
X, X-1, -X
```

for some max level for calls `X`

But sometimes, calling Main gives this kind of output

```
6962
6961
-6963
```

which is actually

```
X, X-1, -(X+1)
```

So the question is, how?

P.S. Also, when I change everything to static, the program totally changes it's behavior, so even sometimes I'm getting more than 3 results.

Edit: When I run this with `-Xss228k` I always get

```
1281
1280
-1281
```

but running with `-Xss1m` again brings me to random stack size and sometimes with the case described above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; you're overflowing the stack and then trying to add more onto it, so obviously the results will be unexpected.

Comment: it's not random science anyway, right? the result must have some explanation

Answer (score 2):

Running your code can result in few other possible outputs. On my PC (Java 8, Windows) I mostly get a pair of values like:

```
7053
-7055
```

but on rare occasions I get:

```
9667
9666
-9667
```

Catching any `java.lang.Error` is not recommended, it's an abnormal condition that JVM may not be able to recover from.

Comment: So how do you think the flow is?

Comment: Perhaps the stack overflows, data there gets corrupted and it's impossible to predict the flow? Wild guess, but it appears to be random.